# PaypalPLus CreatePayment // No BasketData Transmitted

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, paypal-plus

i'm new to Paypal implementation. So please be patient :-)
I'm trying to integrate Paypal Plus into a TYPO3 Shop. With a Simple Paypal Button it does work fine.
For Paypal Plus i create a payment like this:

```js
/*-------------------
Paypal START
---------------------*/
if($('#ppplus').length > 0) {
    $.get("/fileadmin/shop/paypal.php",
        {
            'total': paypal_total,
            'subtotal': paypal_subtotal,
            'tax': paypal_tax,
            'shipping': paypal_shipping,
            'description': paypal_description,
            'invoice_number': 'teetss',
            'recipient_name': paypal_recipient_name,
   'items':itemlist
        },
        function (data, status) {
            var parsed = $.parseJSON(data);
            approvalUrl = parsed.links[1].href;


            var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
                "approvalUrl": approvalUrl,
                "placeholder": "ppplus",
                "mode": "sandbox",
                "country": "DE",
                "language": "DE_de"
            });
        });
}
/*--- Paypal END */
```

The Result looks like this:

```js
{id: "PAY-XXX", intent: "sale", state: "created",…}
create_time: "2018-09-13T06:34:28Z"
id: "PAY-XXX"
intent: "sale"
links: [,…]
0: {href: "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXX", rel: "self",…}
1:  {,…}
href: "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-XXX"
method: "REDIRECT"
rel: "approval_url"
2: {href: "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXX/execute",…}
payer: {payment_method: "paypal"}
payment_method: "paypal"
state: "created"
transactions: [{,…}]
0: {,…}
amount: {total: "34.50", currency: "EUR", details: {subtotal: "24.49", tax: "5.51", shipping: "4.50"}}
currency: "EUR"
details: {subtotal: "24.49", tax: "5.51", shipping: "4.50"}
shipping: "4.50"
subtotal: "24.49"
tax: "5.51"
total: "34.50"
description: "Parkett Herter Shop"
invoice_number: "teetss"
item_list: {}
related_resources: []
```

paypal.php

```html
<?php
$total = htmlspecialchars($_GET["total"]);
$subtotal = htmlspecialchars($_GET["subtotal"]);
$tax = htmlspecialchars($_GET["tax"]);
$shipping = htmlspecialchars($_GET["shipping"]);
$description = htmlspecialchars($_GET["description"]);
$invoice_number = htmlspecialchars($_GET["invoice_number"]);
$recipient_name = htmlspecialchars($_GET["recipient_name"]);
$items = htmlspecialchars($_GET["items"]);

$ch = curl_init();
$data = '{
 "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "'.$total.'",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "'.$subtotal.'",
          "tax": "'.$tax.'",
          "shipping": "'.$shipping.'"
        }
      },
      "description": "'.$description.'",
      "invoice_number": "'.$invoice_number.'",
      "item_list": {'.$items.'}
    }
  ],
  "redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "xxx",
    "cancel_url": "xxx"
  }
}';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json",
  "Authorization: Bearer xxx", 
  "Content-length: ".strlen($data))
);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//print_r($output);
?>
```

So the "Paypal Wall" Iframe is created and I can choose a Payment Option. But when I'm redirected to Paypal there are no Informations about the Customer, the Price... What Am I missing?